# CSS box-shadow not working with table row in Safari

Tags: css, ios, safari, frontend

```
.highlight {
     box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
}
```

I find this style is not working with table row in Safari(iOS 16.1.1), but it works in Chrome 107 and Edge 107.

I tried it with table cells (both <td> and display:table-cells) in Safari, it works fine.

I also tried add

`-webkit-appearance: none;`

But it did not help.

Is anybody would give a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Safari is a bit odd when it comes to tables.
You will have to set the tr to display block and recreate the table behaviour with CSS. It isn't nice, but it works for most cases.

```css
table { 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
td, th { 
  padding-left: 16px; 
  min-width: 150px;
  text-align: left; 
}
tr {
  display: block; 
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>jo</td>
    <td>yippie</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, but my projects use ant design components, and set tr to display block will make the whole table looks weird.

Comment: I am afraid there is no fix then. Safari won't render box-shadows as long as you are not changing the display: attribute